# what exactly is the mathematical function behind excel's SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, linear-algebra

The documentation says:

> SUMPRODUCT:  "Multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products."

What is the name for this mathematical operation?

---

**EDIT**: people have claimed this operation is a dot product. I don't agree. Similar yes, but not exactly.

Look at the behavior of `SUMPRODUCT` below.
In the formula bar, we have `=SUMPRODUCT(A3:B4,D3:E4)`
and on the page we can see:
[image]
I colored the cells to show that what we have is *component-wise multiplication across corresponding cells in the matrices, with summation over all these products.*
There is no 'column vector' \dot 'row vector' operation happening.
If you ignore the lack to transpose, you might be able to call it TWO dot products followed by summation. This isn't just a lone dot, nor is it a matrix multiplication in the most common sense.

Comment: If you are looking for the name of mathematical operation it is [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Math]

Frobenius inner product (stolen from the comment which should have been put as an answer)

When you're dealing with one dimensional matrices, it would be equivalent to a dot product.

Many excel users won't be familiar with the term "dot product" (which is generally not introduced until tertiary education in maths/science) and, as you've pointed out, it's not strictly accurate for two dimensional ranges. It can be considered as being applied here to the vector representations of the arrays, but that's taking a computer science view of the ranges rather than the matrix viewpoint that would be used from a strictly mathematical perspective.

SUMPRODUCT is introduced as a meaningful literal name... the SUM of the PRODUCTS.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the two vectors represented by the two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)  that relates to the sum of the products of the elements of the matrix (I have inserted the link so that it is clearer to you).

It is different from the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition) that is an algebraic operation that takes two equal-length sequences of numbers (usually coordinate vectors) and returns a single number.